# JPanels inside a Gridlayout causing transparency issues

Tags: java, swing, transparency, alpha, grid-layout

I'm new to Java and I can't seem to fix this bug with Translucent backgrounds.

Whenever I change parts of my panel it draws the changes as well as some random pictures of the window.

Clearer pictures of the bug

- http://shujin.homelinux.net/fong/Working.jpg
- http://shujin.homelinux.net/fong/Bugged.jpg

Here is a link to the full working project so you can clearly see the bug. Just give it a minute to load my server is slow http://fong.shujindesigns.net

I made this smaller version of the bug so you can test.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Example1 extends JApplet implements MouseListener {


    Container Con = getContentPane();
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 5, 0, 0));
    JPanel[][] panel2 = new JPanel[5][5];
    JLabel[] label = new JLabel[25];
    Color color;
    int count = 0;

    public void init() {

        int col = 0;
        int row = 0;
        color = new Color(0.00f, 0.24f, 0.70f, 0.50f);

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            if (col > 4) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
        label[i] = new JLabel("test");
        label[i].addMouseListener(this);
        panel2[col][row] = new JPanel();
        panel2[col][row].add(label[i]);
        color = new Color(0.00f, 0.24f, 0.70f, 0.20f);
        panel2[col][row].setBackground(color);
        label[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        panel1.add(panel2[col][row]);
        color = new Color(0.50f, 0.24f, 0.10f, 0.20f);
        panel1.setBackground(color);
        col++;
        }



        Con.add(panel1);
        panel1.setOpaque(false);
        label[5].setText("test2");
    }


    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        label[5].setText("Test 3" + count);
        count++;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {  
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { 
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {  
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `..extends JApplet`  For ease of development/testing, make a hybrid that can also run as an application. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Generate the images in code.

Comment: This was my SSCCEE, I made an edit so this code will work now. The bug persists if I use a translucent.setbackground instead of images.

Sorry I don't know how to make a hybrid application??

Comment: For the sake of future questions & edits (or rather, those of us who suffer reading them) please learn: 1) To check that the preview below the message posting form looks and reads as you expect.  2) How to use code formatting 3) How to insert links & use list points. --  I just spent the last 10 minutes cleaning that up so it formats & reads logically.  On the subject of hybrids.  Have a look through posts mentioning 'hybrid' by [me](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A418556+hybrid) & [trashgod](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+hybrid).  We often post complete code.

Comment: Sorry Andrew Thompson. I spent ages trying to make it look readable and provide all relevent code :( Is this not simple enough?

Comment: After the time I spent reformatting the post, I needed a rest and went off to do other things.  Have not looked at the code yet.

Comment: also, I can't show images or hyperlink more than 2, because I'm new :( and I fixed my links so they work now lol.

Comment: *"hyperlink more than 2"*  Right you are.  My bad on that one.

Comment: BTW - that is a great little SSCCE!  A lot of people make several attempts before they can understand what it means or how to make one.  +1  (Oh, I'm still puzzling over the effect, no answers yet..)

Comment: Thanks for looking :) I've spent like 10+ hours trying to fix it, but I only have limited knowledge. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mouseClicked event, add "repaint()"

If that doesn't work, try invalidate(), repaint()

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    label[5].setText("Test 3" + count);
    count++;

    //revalidate();
    repaint();

}
```